# Query date column from join table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is the schema:

```
Customer (Customer_ID, Name, Address, Phone),
Porder (Customer_ID, Pizza_ID, Quantity, Order_Date), 
Pizza (Pizza_ID, Name, Price).
```

I want to get all customers that ordered a pizza in the last 30 days, based on the Order_Date & who spent the most money in the last 30 days. Can these be combined into one?

Here is what I am trying and I am not sure about DATEDIFF or how the query would calculate the total money.

```
SELECT customer.customer_ID, customer.name FROM customer 
JOIN porder ON customer.customer_ID = porder.customer_ID
GROUP BY customer.customer_ID, customer.name
WHERE DATEDIFF(porder.porder_date,getdate()) between 0 and 30
```

Who spent the most money last 30 days?

```
SELECT porder.customer_ID, porder.pizza_id, porder.quantity FROM order 
JOIN pizza ON porder.pizza_ID = pizza.pizza_ID
GROUP BY porder.customer_ID
WHERE MAX((porder.quantity * pizza.price)) && DATEDIFF(porder.porder_date,getdate()) between 0 and 30
```

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word. This makes it a poor choice for a table/column identifier.

Comment: Do I have to rename the table? How would I identify it?

Comment: You don't have to rename it. You can just use backticks when referencing it.

Comment: It's also really weird that a table of orders would have no order_id. What if a customer orders two different pizzas on the same order?

Comment: You should rename it. Otherwise you will drive one of us bonkers.

Comment: @Strawberry - Good point, but that will be for another day. :)

Comment: So what is the question? Are these queries not producing the desired results?

Comment: @AaronKent, they don't work yes, I am asking if my use of MAX and DATEDIFF are close to correct or if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that functions are blackboxes to query optimizer, so you better make the query fit the index, and not the other way around.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(order.order_date,getdate()) between 0 and 30
```

can be rewritten, so that the query would use plain index on `order_date`

```
WHERE order.order_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Who spent the most money in the last 30 days

```
SELECT 
  o.customer_id, SUM(p.price * o.quantity)
FROM 
  order o
  INNER JOIN pizza p 
    ON o.pizza_id = p.pizza_id
WHERE 
  order_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY o.customer_id
ORDER BY SUM(p.price * o.quantity) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Where is CURRENT_DATE defined? Should it be getdate() ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date

Comment: Oh, MySQL library... I better make use of them. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :) Reference manuals are a great source of knowledge.

Comment: Erm, I think that's "- INTERVAL 30 DAY"

Comment: I have to change the order to order o, so I do WHERE o.order_date and not order.order_date right? Since order is reserved?

Comment: The reason why I'm using o is because I put this as an alias for column `order` in the `FROM` clause. This has nothing to do with `order` word bein reserved :)

Comment: So what is wrong then, they said order is reserved so won't it error?

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Can you execute the query? If not, you always have SQLFiddle.com my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about once you've sorted out your tables, and separated order details from orders.

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT x.*
     , IF(x.i = y.maxi,1,0) is_biggest 
  FROM ints x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(i) maxi FROM ints) y 
    ON y.maxi = x.i;
+---+------------+
| i | is_biggest |
+---+------------+
| 0 |          0 |
| 1 |          0 |
| 2 |          0 |
| 3 |          0 |
| 4 |          0 |
| 5 |          0 |
| 6 |          0 |
| 7 |          0 |
| 8 |          0 |
| 9 |          1 |
+---+------------+
```